# scroll function for multiple id's

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have the following code to have a div stick to the top upon scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
//After scrolling 100px from the top...
if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 72 || (w > 980)) {
    $('#div1').css('top', '0px');

//Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
} else {
    $('#div1').attr('style', '');

}
});
```

Now I want two divs on one page to have the same behaviour. I tried:

```
 $('#div1' || '#div2')
```

but that does not seem to work. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either comma separate them like  `$('#div1, #div2')` or just add a class instead of using id's like  `$('.stickyDiv')` and then

```html
<div class="stickyDiv" id="div1"></div>
<div class="stickyDiv" id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to stick the div on top while scrolling, I suggest you to use a CSS attribute called `position`.

Example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/swetankpoddar/pen/pBamBB)

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp).

Comment: I will try this also, I am only not sure it works in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with position:sticky.

```css
#div1 , #div2 {
    position: sticky;
    top: 72px;
}
```

By **default**, they will behave as **position: relative**. 
When the Parent Element is **scrolled** (passed the 72px point), they will behave like **position: fixed**.

This will happen only within the scrolling of the Parent Element. 
If you want them to be sticky relative to the window, place them as direct children of the <body>.

```html
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</body>
```